# How to save twilio ip message to a database?

Tags: twilio, amazon-dynamodb

I'm discovering twilio ip messaging and i want to make a simple basic chat application. It's not so difficult but i want every sent messages to be stored in a database.

I was seeking some solutions into the twilio user interface but no such things to help me to solve this issue.

I am using  amazon dynamodb. How could i process it so that each time I relogin to the chat i could see  messages from the last session ?

Comment: Twilio sends data to your server. How you save it is up to you and your server.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. How can i catch these data ? Sorry i'm new in twilio

Comment: Being new isn't an excuse for not doing any research. They provide quickstart tutorials that cover all this. https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I think you are looking for the onMessageSend webhook:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks

You can configure for IP Messaging Service instance with a URL for this webhook either in the account portal or via the rest API.  Twilio will request that URL whenever a client sends a message to the channel.  The webhook will include the sender id, channel id and message which you can save to your database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what i was seeking. You solved my problem.